# The artifact directory does not exist in VSTS releases

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an issue with the Release in VSTS. Somehow the path is not recognized although I'm sure it exists and accessible. I've tried to share the folder to everyone and changed service account of VSTS Agent but it's still the same. Anyone has ideas? Thanks

```
2017-09-29T10:26:47.4300253Z Directory '\\build_ezcm_01\build\Result\EZCM-Maven-CI\20170929.11\drop' does not exist. Falling back to parent directory: \\build_ezcm_01\build\Result\EZCM-Maven-CI\20170929.11
2017-09-29T10:26:47.7079394Z An error occurred during download: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.ArtifactDownloadException: The artifact directory does not exist: \\build_ezcm_01\build\Result\EZCM-Maven-CI\20170929.11. It can happen if the password of the account factoryvm-az179\buildguest is changed recently and is not updated for the agent. If this is the case, please consider re-configuring the agent.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.BuildArtifact.<DownloadArtifactAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.BuildArtifact.<DownloadAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.<>c__DisplayClass34_2.<<DownloadArtifacts>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.RetryExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Which agent did you use for the release, Hosted agent or private agent? If you were used private agent, please login the machine which the private agent is located, and try to access to the share path `\\build_ezcm_01\build\Result\EZCM-Maven-CI\20170929.11\drop` to make sure it's accessible.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT: I'm using a private agent. I've tried again to access the folder and it is still accessible.

Answer (score 4):

Check the agent queue for your release.

I had the same error message about FactoryVM and password - I was attempting a nuget push using a network share. It worked great while the nuget task was part of the build (skipping artifacts and pushing from build dir), but started failing when I moved it to a release and had to get the packages from the fileshare for my artifacts.

Turned out that my newly created release was using a Hosted Queue (VS2017) while I was using a Private Agent. In the (currently new) editor this can be set by clicking on the "Agent Phase" block under "Tasks". Switching the queue solved this issue.

[image: change agent]

Comment: Thanks @Volkirith. I have already deleted my release configuration and changed to a difference approach so I cannot test your recommendation.

Comment: It worked for me - thank you so much - never would have thought of this!